# AWS MediaTailor Server-side Event Tracking

Tags: amazon-web-services, vast, aws-mediatailor

I am trying to log different events like start, stop etc. when the video is played.
For this, I have configured URLs in VAST XML in <Tracking> XML tag. But  the tracking URLs are not getting 'hit' when the Ad is played (these URLs are embedded in the VAST XML).
For now, I am not using any ADS. Rather, I am using VAST XML in ADS server URL in AWS MediaTailor configuration.

Below is the code snippet:

```
 <Tracking event="start"><![CDATA[https://myapplication.com/tracking/start]]></Tracking>
 <Tracking event="firstQuartile"><![CDATA[https://myapplication.com/tracking/firstQuartile]]></Tracking>
```

Does anyone have an idea on why could this be?

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in your cloudwatch logs in the AdDecisionServerInteractions log group? Are there errors from events firing or are they not firing at all?

Can you also file a support ticket and attach the entire VAST XML (so we can validate its syntax), or post it here?

The main thing to watch out for here when doing static testing is to make sure the syntax is to VAST spec. Looking at a sample VAST from a real ad server like DFP is helpful:

https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator=

Comment: 1. There are no error on AdDecisionServerInteractions log group. And the events are hit - i can see the ads when the video is played on Player. 2. I validated the VAST XML with Vast XML Validator. 3. When i copy paste the XML on JW Player Stream Tester, all  events are properly logged on my Application URL.

Comment: So the tracking events are getting hit then? That seems to be working as intended then. Specifically if you see in the AdDecisionServerInteractions log group "eventType = BEACON_FIRED" then you know that the tracking events are getting triggered

Comment: Yes, i can see this "eventType = BEACON_FIRED" in logs. But only when i use tracking URL of AWS like"/v1/tracking/". Here, i am trying to log the events on my application, so i have a created a REST API and i deployed it on EC2 instance. When i use my application's urls in VAST XML, in cloud watch i dont see "eventType = BEACON_FIRED" in logs.

Comment: Also, i have one more question - that is there any requirement that the domain of Ad Decision server and tracking URL should be same?